# Facing java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while initializing page factory class after upgrading appium from Version 5.0.4 to Version 6.1.0

Tags: maven, appium, appium-ios, appium-android, page-factory

I have recently updated my appium java-client maven dependency to facilitate touch features.

Facing the below error while running the script which was executing fine earlier.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.utils.ProxyFactory.getEnhancedProxy(ProxyFactory.java:52)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.utils.ProxyFactory.getEnhancedProxy(ProxyFactory.java:33)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.proxyForAnElement(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.access$0(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:215)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator$1.proxyForLocator(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.decorate(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.decorate(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
    at org.framework.adib.selendroidTestApp.pages.HomePage.<init>(HomePage.java:18)
    at org.framework.adib.selendroidTestApp.StepDefinition.SelendroidTest.user_opens_Selendroid_application(SelendroidTest.java:39)
    at ✽.Given User opens Selendroid application(src/test/java/org/framework/adib/selendroidTestApp/Feature/MyApplicationFeature.feature:5)
```

**POM definition**

```
<!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Class definition:**

```
public class HomePage {

    private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    public HomePage(AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        try {
            PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Base class for initializing driver in Core project:
`

```
private static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> androiddriver;

private static IOSDriver<IOSElement> iosdriver;

/**
 * Gets the driver.
 *
 * @return the driver
 */
public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> getAndroidDriver() {
    return androiddriver;
}

/**
 * Gets the driver.
 *
 * @return the driver
 */
public static IOSDriver<IOSElement> getIosDriver() {
    return iosdriver;
}

private static AppiumDriverLocalService service;
private static AppiumServiceBuilder builder;
private static DesiredCapabilities cap;

/**
 * Method to initialize the appium driver.
 * 
 * @param: appURL
 *             location of the apk file
 * @param: CONFIG
 *             Config properties of the application under test
 */
public static void openApplication(String appUrl, Properties config) throws MalformedURLException {
    File appDir = new File(appUrl);

    File app = new File(appDir, config.getProperty("APP_NAME"));

    // defining appium url
    String appiumUrl = "http://" + config.getProperty("APPIUM_IP") + ":" + config.getProperty("APPIUM_PORT")
            + "/wd/hub";

    boolean isRunning = checkIfServerIsRunnning(config.getProperty("APPIUM_IP"),
            Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("APPIUM_PORT")));

    if (!isRunning) {
        startServer(config);
    }

    switch (config.getProperty("OS")) {
        default:
            // Log.info("OS version is not correct");
            break;
        case "ANDROID": {
            // Defining APIUM Capabilities
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            // cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, config.getProperty("PLATFORM_VERSION"));
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, config.getProperty("EMU_NAME"));
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, config.getProperty("BROWSER_NAME"));
            cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, config.getProperty("APP_PACKAGE"));
            cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, config.getProperty("APP_ACTIVITY"));
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, config.getProperty("EMU_NAME"));
            // if(config.getProperty("IS_PHYSICAL").equalsIgnoreCase("FALSE"))
            // {
            // //To run with emulator
            // cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.u"avd",
            // config.getProperty("EMU_NAME"));
            //
            // }
            androiddriver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(appiumUrl), cap);

            // Implicit wait definition
            androiddriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("TIME_OUT")),
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            System.out.println("The session ID for " + config.getProperty("EMU_NAME") + " is : " + ""
                    + androiddriver.getSessionId());
            break;
        }`
```

Setup class in Test project in Test project:

```
    public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    public static XlsReader XLR = null;
    Scenario scenario = null;
    public static Properties CONFIG;
    static CommonFunctionAndroidImpl com_fun = null;
    protected static String appUrl;

@Before
public void beforeMethod(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {

    DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");

    // getting instance of scenario
    this.scenario = scenario;
    Log.startTestCase(scenario.getName());

    // Initialize Configurations
    CONFIG = Config.initializeConfig();

    // Initialize App location
    appUrl = (System.getProperty("user.dir") + CONFIG.getProperty("APP_URL"));
    Log.info("App location:" + appUrl);

    // Initialize Appium Driver
    BaseClass.openApplication(appUrl, CONFIG);
    driver = BaseClass.getAndroidDriver();

    // Initialize XCEL for Data
    XLR = new XlsReader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + CONFIG.getProperty("DATA_FILE"));

    // Initialize Common Function
    com_fun = new CommonFunctionAndroidImpl(driver);
}`
```

Actual Test Class:

```
CommonFunctionAndroidImpl com_fun = Setup.com_fun;

// Variables for accessing XLS methods
XlsReader XLR = Setup.XLR;

String name, userName, email, pwd, lang, adds;
int rowNum = 0;

HashMap<String, String> data = null;

// Page objects for all the application pages
protected HomePage hp;
protected static NewRegistrationPage rp;
protected static ConfirmRegistrationPage cp = null;

@Given("^User opens Selendroid application$")
public void user_opens_Selendroid_application() throws Throwable {

    hp = new HomePage(Setup.driver);
}

@When("^User clicks on Create New User icon$")
public void user_clicks_on_Create_New_User_icon() throws Throwable {
    rp = hp.clickNewRegBttn();
}
```

Home Page class:

```
private AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

public HomePage(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    try {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@AndroidFindBy(id = "io.selendroid.testapp:id/startUserRegistration")
public WebElement newRegBttn;

@AndroidFindBy(id = "android:id/title")
public WebElement appTitle;

@AndroidFindBy(id = "io.selendroid.testapp:id/showToastButton")
public WebElement displayToast;

@AndroidFindBy(id = "io.selendroid.testapp:id/showPopupWindowButton")
public WebElement displayPopup;

public NewRegistrationPage clickNewRegBttn() {
    newRegBttn.click();
    return new NewRegistrationPage(driver);
}

public void clickDisplayToast() {
    displayToast.click();
}

public void clickDisplayPopup() {
    displayPopup.click();
}

public boolean appTitleTextDisplayed() {
    return appTitle.isDisplayed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **AndroidDriver** to **AppiumDriver** and replace **AndroidElement** with **MobileElement** or **WebElement**.

```
public HomePage(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {

    try {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Suban,

I tried updating the driver from AndroidDriver to AppiumDriver.. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I use your original definition, but Suban helped me with this problem about a month ago.  In my case I had to define the driver as static.  I'm not happy with that solution because I don't think I should have had to have made the driver static, but it worked.  Frankly, I don't know why my system is working at all now, but it does.

Comment: I might be wrong on who helped me, apologies if I have the wrong guy.

Comment: @BillHileman if you don't use driver as static you need to initialize driver each time you use in another class.

Comment: So guys I have structured my project in two different maven projects as below
1. Core: Have all common functions and initialization methods
2. Test Project: Actual test classes and Pgae classes

I have defined the driver as static in both the project, still the same doesn't work.

Comment: After getting stuck with the issue for couple of months the only solution which I could find was initializing the objects as WebElements as below

`public class AppLandingPage {
public AppLandingPage() {
    PageFactory.initElements(BaseClass.iosdriver, this);
}

@FindBy(id = "Yes")
public WebElement haveAccountConfirm;`
The performance of the scripts have improved drastically and also working on iOS 12.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

I was facing the same issue, and this is because of inappropriate version between java client or TestNG or older version dependencies. Once I updated the java client version in pom with the version of TestNG as below, issue got resolved.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
  <version>7.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this issue. MobileElement along with PageFactory throws this exception. I searched a lot of discussion forums, no exact solution is available to fix this issue. I changed the MobileElement to WebElement and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

set your android driver like this 'private AndroidDriver < WebElement > driver = null;'
and degrade java-client to 7.4.1.
your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I am using java 17, appium java client 8.3.0

running individual testng test then add "--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" vm arguments (Run configuration)

[image]

2. running by pom.xml
   [image]